# Detect item exiting view in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

[image]Currently I'm showing a `CustomScrollView` inside a bottomSheet.

```
CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: [
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: MonthViewHeader(widget.weekDays),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return MonthView(
                index == 0 ? widget._today : Jalali(widget._today.year, widget._today.month, 1).addMonths(index),
                index != 0,
                selectedDate,
                (DateTime date) => {
                      setSheetState(() {
                        selectedDate = date;
                        widget.onDateChange(date);
                      })
                    });
          }),
        )
      ],
    )
```

`SliverPersistentHeader` stays on top of the list on scroll and `SliverList` scrolls beneath it.
I want to check which item index is being entered/exited view on scroll. I want to know that so I can change my `SliverPersistentHeader` text.
One approach would be to calculate scrollOffset and give each item static height.
But that's not very optimal since item 0 of `SilverList` might have a smaller height so I can give it fixed height.
Is there any way to detect item entering/exiting view inside `SilverList`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out this plugin:

> flutter_sticky_header

It seems that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, I have just one header, and its text is being updated. The provided library makes multiple headers and sticks the most recent item's header